# Show that the element $(t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t)^2+a(t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t)$ $zero$ element

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. For $a,b \in R$ with $ab=2$, define the ring $A:=R[t]/(t^2+at)$.

> Show that  the element $(t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t)^2+a(t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t)$ of $A$ is the $zero$ element.

I think this answer is related to tensor product and I am not good at it.

Assume that $T=t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t$. If we can show that $(t^2+at) = (T^2+aT)$, then we are done. In other word, if we have to show $R[t]/(t^2+at) \cong R[T]/(T^2+aT)$.

Define the map $f: R[t] \to R[T]/(T^2+aT)$. It is a homomorphism.

How to show the ideal $(t^2+at)$ is the kernel of this homomorphism?

Please help.

**Edit:**

As suggested below, to compute $T^2+aT$, we at first compute $T^2$ as follows:

The basis of $A$ is $\{1,t\}$  and hence basis of $A\otimes A$ is $\{1 \otimes 1, 1 \otimes t, t \otimes 1, t \otimes t \}$. Now $T$ being an element of $A \otimes A$, \begin{align} T^2=T\cdot T&=(t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t) \cdot (t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t) \\  &= (t \otimes 1)(t \otimes 1)+(t \otimes 1)(1 \otimes t)+(t \otimes 1)(bt \otimes t)+(1 \otimes t)(t \otimes 1)+ \\ & \hspace{0.7 cm} (1 \otimes t)(1 \otimes t)+(1 \otimes t)(bt \otimes t)+(bt \otimes t)(t \otimes 1)+(bt \otimes t)(1 \otimes t)+ \\ & \hspace{0.7 cm} (b t \otimes t)(bt \otimes t) \\ &=t^2 \otimes 1+ t \otimes t+bt^2 \otimes t+t \otimes t+1 \otimes t^2+ bt \otimes t^2+bt^2 \otimes t+bt \otimes t^2+ \\ & \hspace{0.7 cm} b^2t^2 \otimes t^2 \\ &= -a(t \otimes 1)+2(t \otimes t)-2ab(t \otimes t)-2ab(t \otimes t)-a(1 \otimes t) +a^2b^2 (t \otimes t) \\ & \hspace{0.7 cm} (\because t^2=-at) \\&=-a(t \otimes 1)-a(1 \otimes t)-4ab (t \otimes t)+(ab)^2 (t \otimes t) \\ &=-a(t \otimes 1)-a(1 \otimes t)-4 (t \otimes t) \ (\because ab=2)\end{align}
and
\begin{align} aT &=a(t \otimes 1+1 \otimes t+bt \otimes t) \\
&= a(t \otimes 1)+a (1 \otimes t)+a(bt \otimes t) \\ &=a(t \otimes 1)+a (1 \otimes t)+ab(t \otimes t) \\
&= a(t \otimes 1)+a (1 \otimes t)+2(t \otimes t)
\end{align}

Then \begin{align} T^2+aT&=-a(t \otimes 1)-a(1 \otimes t)-4 (t \otimes t)+a(t \otimes 1)+a (1 \otimes t)+2(t \otimes t) \\
&= -2(t \otimes t) \end{align}
I think my calculation in $T^2$ is wrong.

Comment: As an $R$-module $A$ is free with basis $\{1,t\}$. Therefore it would make sense to expand that highlighted element, and write it using the $R$-basis $\{1\otimes1, 1\otimes t,t\otimes1,t\otimes t\}$ of $A\otimes A$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes, $T=0(1 \otimes 1)+1(t \otimes 1)+1(1 \otimes t)+b(t \otimes t)$.  The map $A \to A \otimes A $ is isomorphism. I can feel $T$ is $zero$ in $A$ but unable to show

Comment: Calculate $T^2+aT$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I can't compute the square $T^2$. Is $T^2=(0 \times 0)(1 \otimes 1)+(1 \times 1)(t \otimes 1)+(1 \times 1) (1 \otimes t)+(b \times b)(t \otimes t)$, where $\times$ is multiplication in the ring $A$ ??  Please help me

Comment: Surely that has been explained in your book? We have
$$(x\otimes y)\cdot (u\otimes v)=(xu)\otimes (yv)$$ and extend $R$-linearly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I have still a problem here. what does it mean by square of a tensor in general ? Can you please explain a little bit ?

Comment: In general there is no way. $A\otimes A$ becomes a ring only because $A$ is an $R$-algebra (= a ring with multiplication compatible the $R$-module structure). If $U$ and $V$ are just any $R$-modules, there is no natural to way to turn $U\otimes  V$ into a ring. OTOH if $A$ and $B$ are both $R$-algebras, then $A\otimes B$ becomes a ring because we have a multiplication defined on the individual factors of elementary tensors. Scores of details to check to be sure that the product is well-defined. Consult your book for them.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, just for clarification. Is $T^2=T\cdot T$ ? where $\cdot$ is multplication in the $R$-algebra $A$

Comment: $T$ is not an element of $A$. It is an element of $A\otimes A$. You need to use the multiplication of $A\otimes A$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen,ok thanks

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Can you check the calculation in the question above (Edited part) ?

Comment: That's the idea! Upvoting. Remember that the factors in all those tensor products are elements of $A$. So for example $t^2\equiv t^2-(t^2+at)=-at$ etc. In other words, the goal is to write them as $R$-linear combinations of $1\otimes1, 1\otimes t$ $t\otimes 1$ and $t\otimes t$. In some of the terms you still have $t^2$ and such.

Comment: Anyway, isn't the goal to show that $T^2+aT=0$ in the ring $A\otimes A$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, We know for scalar $r \in k$, we have the property $r(a \otimes b)=ra \otimes b=a \otimes rb$ holds in $A \otimes A$? Does similar (but not scalar factor) property $t^2 \otimes 1=t(t \otimes 1)=t^2(1 \otimes 1)=t \otimes t=t(1 \otimes 1)$  holds true?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes, We need to show $T^2+aT$  is $zero$ element in $A \otimes A$

Comment: $t(t\otimes1)$ is ambiguous unless you specify how $A\otimes A$ is an $A$-module. But, you should have never gotten such a term! I think you get $t^2\otimes 1$ as the first term instead. But, you really should not be studying tensor products while quotient rings are a mystery. Is it clear to you why $t^2=-at$ in $A$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, yes, I understand $t^2+at$  or any element generated by it vanishes in $A$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116789/discussion-between-masmath-and-jyrki-lahtonen).